# Is there a method to grab whatever is between the option tag?

Tags: javascript, html

Lets say I have a select with some options inside it.

```
<select>
  <option value = 1>dog</option>
  <option value = 2>cat</option>
  <option value = 3>bird</option>
</select>
```

Is there a way to grab whatever is between the option tag if our value is something different? For instance how to grab 'dog'. 'cat', or 'bird'

EDIT: MORE DESCRIPTION

Comment: What do you mean "grab whatever". Give us an example of code, with what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: You can select the option by `id`, `class` whatever and then access the innerHTML. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Comment: You can querySelector the options but I don't think that's what you actually want.  You likely want the text of a selected option.  But you need to state exactly what you want clearly so you don't get a torrent of guesses.

Comment: Sorry, I should mention grab 'dog', 'cat', 'bird'

Comment: `$("select option:selected").text();`

Comment: [Option elements have a `.text` and a `.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement)

Comment: @Keloo No, don't use `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

Select the elements, then do whatever you want with it

```js
document.querySelectorAll('select option').forEach(e =>
  console.log(`found option with value: ${e.value} and innerText: ${e.innerText}`)
)
```

```html
<select>
  <option value=1>dog</option>
  <option value=2>cat</option>
  <option value=3>bird</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get `text` from all `<option>` tags by taking `document.getElementsByTagName` for the wanted tags.

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
    document.getElementsByTagName('option'), 
    e => console.log(e.text)
);
```

```html
<select>
  <option value = 1>dog</option>
  <option value = 2>cat</option>
  <option value = 3>bird</option>
</select>
```

Comment: While the OP said "*grab whatever is between the option tags*" and `innerHTML` literally does that, I think they actually want to get the description *text* - and there are much better ways to do that than `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text inside the `option` tag using jQuery in this way: `$("select option").text()` - this will return a list ['dog', 'cat', 'bird']

p.s if you want to filter with a specific value, then use: `$("select option[value='1']").text()`

Comment: Why do you think this requires jQuery?

Comment: Is it imposible without just plain javascript?

Comment: Of course it's possible with plain javascript, see other answers, they provided good examples ;)

Answer (score 0):

Answered using jquery because i love it

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#dropdown').on('change',function(){   
    alert($(this).val() + $(this).find(':selected').text());      
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value = 1>dog</option>
  <option value = 2>cat</option>
  <option value = 3>bird</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

using javascript , getting selected option's text :

```
 <select onchange="getTextVal(this)">
 <option value = 1>dog</option>
 <option value = 2>cat</option>
 <option value = 3>bird</option>
 </select>
```

And javascript :

```
function getTextVal(e){
  console.log(e.options[e.selectedIndex].text);
  }
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a5fqrohj/4/) :